# Datagridview records in CrystalReport

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, crystal-reports

I am trying to print the records from datagridview in CrystalReport.

I have the following code to pouplate the datagridview.

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data   Source=C:\\dbaza2.mdb");
    DataTable dataT; 

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataT = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.SifraP = Table2.SifraM AND Table2.Mesec = @Mesec AND Table1.Fakultet = @Fakultet ORDER BY Table.Zvawe", con);
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mesec", comboBox1.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fakultet", comboBox2.Text);
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

        da.Fill(dataT);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataT;

    }
```

And to print the crystal report I have the following code

```
protected PoFakultetForm izvestaj = new PoFakultetForm();

private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PoFakultetReport raporti = new PoFakultetReport();
        raporti.SetDataSource(dataT);
        izvestaj.reportSource(raporti);
        izvestaj.Show();
    }
```

The problem is that the Datagridview is populated correctly but in the CrystalReport the data is duplicated 4x times.

How can I set the same data from the datagridview to CrystalReport?

Answer (score 0):

In crystal report have parts, like Report Header,Page Header,Details and follows the footer section. If you placed in details section part it will be repeated based on conditional data and if you place at page header then data will be appeared one time but repeated in every page and if you placed in Report Header then it will be shown one time only, So please check where you placed the data fields